# Is my UML Diagram Correct for the attached code?

Tags: java, uml

My professor gave us this program but did not explain UML to us at all and I am wondering if I have made this diagram correctly.

CODE:

```
package p1;
public class MyProg {
    static int i = 5;
    private Integer j = new Integer(10);
    protected double k = 2.5;
    public MyProg() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        MyProg mp = new MyProg();  
    }

    void m1(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    void m1(String str, int n){
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static int getI(){   
        return MyProg.i;  
    }

    protected Integer getJ(){   
        return new Integer(j);
    }

    double getK(){  
       return new Double(k);   
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In my oponion:
1.

Comment: In my oponion:
1. You don't have to add parameter name into your class diagram. (Your main's args and m1's str and n)
2. Your main method parameter type is incorrect (it's String[], not String)
3. in or out parameter here hard to say since it should come from design view, not from the code.

Comment: You may specificy the initial values in UML as well: i : int = 5

Comment: i and j are not strings, but int and Integer respectively. The primitive types in UML are Integer, String, Boolean, Real and UnlimitedNatural (see UML spec 21.2), so I wouldn't know how to indicate the difference between the Java types int and Integer in UML.

Answer (score 2):

On your diagram:

- As already mentioned i and j are not string
- in main operation args parameter is some sort of array so you are missing the multiplicity indicator (asterisk in square brackets before closing round bracket). So the line should look like `+ main(in args: String[*])`. Of course underscored
- in m1 operation n should have unspecified type
- initial values should be specified as already mentioned in comments
- you can use standard stereotype <> at MyProg operation to mark it as a constructor. Some books suggest not to model constructor unless it's non-standard (i.e. requires some parameters)
- I would be very careful about in vs inout indicator for parameters. In Java the objects are passed through reference by default which means the parameter is inout, not in. In C++ it's the contrary situation, a parameter is passed through value i.e. it's in.

Comment: Second bullet is not quite correct. The string array type for the args parameter can be specified in UML as follows:  +main (in args : String[*])

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl you're right. Thanks for the mention. I've corrected the answer accordingly and added an example to make it clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I've never been much for being too obsessive about details of UML myself (I've definitely seen design meetings that descended into discussions of the finer points of UML rather than about the design itself), but a few minor points:

- You usually wouldn't want to include private variables, methods, etc. on a class diagram because that's an implementation detail (not a design detail). **Edit:** This point probably depends somewhat on the purpose of your diagram - some people would argue that it's acceptable to include those under certain circumstances (e.g. if your primary purpose is to communicate your implementation rather than your design).
- A few of these methods (e.g. `double getK()`) are missing access modifiers. While it's technically syntactically legal to rely on the defaults, it's always better to be explicit about your intent.

Comment: The default visibility in Java is 'package', but the default visibility in UML is 'public' (UML spec 7.8.12.5). To indicate 'package' visibility in UML, use a tilde (~).

Comment: If you show private properties or not depends on what level the diagram is made. As I understand the task is to model (document) actual code in which case usage of private properties is absolutely OK. Besides you might want to show that some information is stored but not exposed or some behaviour exists internally even on modelling level and then you model such properties as private as well.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Is seems as if the specs list the visibilities '+', '-', '#' and '~'  in 9.5.4, but do not define anywhere, which is which :o) Until now I didn't spot the tilde anywhere. EA seems to use a dash just like for private.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I can't find the definitions of the symbols in the UML spec either. I have checked EA 9 and EA 12 and both use the tilde for visibility 'package'. If you zoom in, you can see it.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Funny. Now it's there :-) Actually I never ever have really used anything else than private/public.

Comment: @ThomasKilian and www.admiraalit.nl the definition of those is in 7.8.24.3 and it was there (well, not always under this particular number) at least since ptc/2012-10-24 version of the 2.5 spec (I don't have older versions to compare ;-) ).

Comment: @Ister : Section 7.8.24.3 does not say that '+' means public, '-' means private etc.

Comment: The only indication is the order of the symbols in the constraint. But there IS no definition. One might report a bug :o) http://issues.omg.org/issues/create-new-issue

Comment: I entered one but it was immediately lost >:-O

Comment: @Ister That's a fair point - personally I usually exclude them since the purpose of the diagrams is usually to communicate the design, but I can see why you might want to include them under certain circumstances. I edited to include that point.

Comment: @ThomasKilian indeed. And I agree it should be claimed as a documentation bug. Other place with a hint about meaning of those symbols is in 11.4.5 by comparing 11.16 (where operators are used) and 11.17 (where a visibility grouping option is used). Yet, quite theoretically those figures don't have to show exactly the same class Window. Moreover you have there only public, protected and private so you need to analyse that package is the remaining one (tilde).

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to paste all answers in a single one...

- In the program you use `Integer`, `String`, `Double` (as being classes, I guess) and sometimes mix `int` while in your class diagram you use all lower case (being primitives) and always `integer`. That should be aligned.